# Understanding gap between socket creation and select() system call

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I am aware that `select()` will be triggered whenever there is a data in the registered socket buffer.

what will happen if there is a delay between these two statements.

```
FD_SET(listener, &read_fds);              //    &
(select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
```

what will happen if packet arrives between these two statements?

```
//create socket and listen for packets       &
FD_SET(listener, &read_fds);
```

Assume that `recv()` is done once select is triggered.

- What will happen if a packet arrives before the `select()` call is
  made.?
- does `FD_ISSET` still detects the packet which is already in
  socket buffer or it will be detected only if new packet arrives and
  select gets triggered?

### Sample code:

```
// add the listener to the master set

FD_SET(listener, &master);

// keep track of the biggest file descriptor

fdmax = listener; // so far, it's this one

// main loop

for(;;) {
    read_fds = master; // copy it
    if (select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("select");
        exit(4);
    }

    // run through the existing connections looking for data to read
    for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++) {
        if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) { // we got one!!
```

Comment: Note: `select()` will never be triggered automatically (on events); however when calling it, the return depends on the socket __blocking__ flag.

Comment: @CristiFati Neither of those statements is correct. Triggering on events is exactly what `select()` is *for;* and `select()` doesn't care about the blocking/non-blocking mode of sockets.

Comment: Ah yes, regarding the first part I misunderstood the question (`select()` _function_ getting called automatically as it was some kind of a callback), and regarding the second part I made a confusion about select and the other socket functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Understanding gap between socket creation and `select()` system call

There is no gap between socket creation and `select()` in your question.

> I am aware that select() will be triggered whenever there is a data in the registered socket buffer.

That's true for read events and it applies to the socket *receive* buffer of connected sockets. It *also* triggers when there is an inbound connection on a listening socket, or room in the socket send buffer for send events.

> what will happen if there is a delay between these two statements.

```
FD_SET(listener, &read_fds);              //    &
(select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
```

Nothing bad. Any event that occurs between them will still be signalled. But the first statement isn't a socket creation, contrary to your title.

> what will happen if packet arrives between these two statements?

```
//create socket and listen for packets       &
FD_SET(listener, &read_fds);
```

The socket send buffer exists from the moment the socket is created, so the data will go into the buffer, so when `select()` runs it will see that and trigger a read event.

> Assume that recv() is done once select is triggered.
>   What will happen if a packet arrives before the select() call is made.?

The socket send buffer exists from the moment the socket is created, so the data will go into the buffer, so when `select()` runs it will see that and trigger a read event.

> does FD_ISSET still detects the packet which is already in socket buffer

Yes.

> or it will be detected only if new packet arrives and select gets triggered?

It will always be detected.

Answer (score 1):

If data is waiting to be read, `select` will return immediately, and `FD_ISSET` will return true for the file descriptor that the data arrived on.  It doesn't matter if data arrived before or after `select` was called.

Answer (score 1):

`select()` completes immediately if one or more of the watched conditions is already active; otherwise it blocks until one or more of the watched conditions becomes active (or the timeout, if specified, expires).